# I want to ignore duplicate values from datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to ignore duplicate values and only want to get distinct value from data table.

How can I skip duplicate, non-distinct values?

My code:

```
foreach (string csvRow in ReadCSV.Split('\n'))
{

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow) && csvRow.Length == 11) 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i<tblcsv.Rows.Count;i++ )
        {
            if (ReadCSV[i].Equals(tblcsv.Columns.ToString()))
            continue;
        }
    
        tblcsv.Rows.Add();
        int count = 0;
    
        foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(',')) 
        {
            tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its obvious the duplicate entry is in the table.

And you can use Distinct() before .ToList()

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Select(x => x.type).Distinct())
```